# Avoiding too much Zinc when using Antibiotics

Tags: dogs, diet, medicines, eating

Our dog is currently taking antibiotics, specifically Cephalexin in tablet form, as well as Ofloxacin (Ocuflox) eye drops. In addition, she is taking Carprofen, which is an NSAID.

When reading about these medications I noticed that you should avoid taking Oral Zinc too close to taking these medications as it can minimize this effect.

My question is, is this generally only a concern when supplementing Zinc, or is it a concern for getting too much from food as well?

I ask as we give her her tablets with her food (twice a day), and I know red meat is high in Zinc, so was curious if we should avoid giving her red meat at this time?

Looking at [this page](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1747-0080.2007.00197.x) it shows the lean component of Australian beef has an average of *4.6mg* of Zinc per *100g*.

[image]

As an example, we feed our dog about 250g/day, but obviously it's not all going to be straight beef, there will be other ingredients too. I guess you could say 150g per day if she ate it for both meals.

I also did wonder if cooking it changes it's nutritional profile (sometimes she eats raw food, sometimes commercial cooked), but it seems, according to [this page](https://meatscience.org/TheMeatWeEat/topics/meat-in-the-diet/article/2017/02/23/how-are-nutrients-retained-during-cooking), cooking meat does not reduce the quantity or availability of Zinc.

Now, according to [this page](https://thepossiblecanine.com/zinc), at 6.1kg, it seems her daily requirements would be *7.76mg's* a day.

So, based on *150g* of beef a day (as an example), she would be getting *6.9mg* of Zinc.

So, should we avoid feeding her high Zinc content with these tablets / eye drops, or is that only really a concern with Oral Zinc, and if so, why?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask the vet that is prescribing all this medication.

Comment: I agree with @AsheraH, just call your vet or a vet clinic and ask them.

Comment: You could also ask in medicine.SE about the effect zinc has to the medication

Comment: @AsheraH She is going back for a checkup in a couple days so I guess I will ask then. :)